# How to call multiple methods in Route model function

Tags: ember.js, components

I have a template named index. In this Index route I am already sending a model.

**For Example:** Think it as status,comments.

In Index template I am having status related data.

If I want to render comments for that status. I need another template.

If I have a another template. I must define a route.

Instead of that I am having comments related data in my components.

Now, I am calling this components in my index template. like below

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    {{status-comments}}
</script>
```

Here, I can't able to render the comments data.

Because already in Index Route staus related model function is there. Hence I wasn't able to set comments model in same index route ?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of ember-data are you using? If you are using the latest version of ember-data you can include links to the URI location of hasMany relation data and then the app will asynchronously fetch the data when you request it in the template, or from any other place.  Search the ember-data source code for 'links'.

```
App.Status = DS.Model.extend({
   ...
   comments: DS.hasMany('comment')
});
```

Status json returned from server:

```
{
  ...
  links: {
     comments: 'http://app.com/api/status/1445/comments'
  }
}
```

Status template:

```
{{#each comment in status}}

{{/each}}
```

The links attribute tells ember-data where to find the hasMany relation.